# Strange carousel with jquery bx slider

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I´ve got two carousels and the first one should work like the second one but it dowsnt, ca you help me with that problem?

```
 $('.slider1').bxSlider({
      slideWidth: 960,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 8,
    slideMargin: 0

  });

    http://jsfiddle.net/qF39p/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this the solution on github https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/pull/481#issuecomment-38479768

Problem is probably in jquery 1.11

Answer (score 0):

Note: Use bxslider without specifying slide width and also margin apply only in css it take effect from there.

- to solve this problem remove float:left;and add display:inline-block in your list element.

  $('.slider1').bxSlider({ 
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 8, 
   });
- Also try to remove max slides because its make your slider static.
- if your carousel contain different height in every item then use adaptiveHeight:true in function.